# Where i need to get Kafka Connect distributed jars and plugins in Azure Kafka for HD Insight?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to configure Kafka connect distributed, but i didn't find any jars for configure Kafka connect in Azure HD Insight.

Can you please help me with my above query.

Comment: Apache Kafka _comes with_ Kafka Connect, it is not a separate thing to download... Maybe you can clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure/kafka-connect-with-hdinsight-managed-kafka/ba-p/1547013

Download the relevant Kafka Plugins from the Confluent Hub to your plugin.path setting

Kafka Connect plugin for streaming data to kafka:
Azure Blob Storage Sink Connector

https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-blob-storage